# How can I stop the automatic string to number conversion in perl?

Tags: perl

Well, when I named a folder with "4.0" in backup and store the name in database. When I get it from the database using perl, I changed to "4". How can I stop the automatic conversion?

Comment: Or can I get other solutions?

Comment: It most certainly didn't do this just to annoy you. Have you used the value in an arithmetic operation? Like `0 + $filename` or something?

Comment: Is the data type of your database field `INT` or `VARCHAR` (or likewise something that has a series of characters)?

Comment: No, the database field is string. The name read from database is string "4.00". To send the data to UI, I should use json. I think this results in the problem. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Who votes these questions up? There is no source code and no relevant info.

Comment: You need to show the relevant code. Otherwise this is just guesswork.

Comment: "How can I solve this problem?"  -- There's no problem that I can see (because you didn't post the code that's giving you trouble).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things that can go wrong here.

- The value you have in the variable might have changed before you insert it into the database
- The database driver may think it's a number and might change it
- The database server might change it before it stores it
- And, the same things might happen on the way out.

Check each of those things to see there the value changes. Then, focus on that part and add to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you can't.  The DBD driver you're using (you didn't specify) is probably written in XS, and is using its own heuristics to figure this out.  Most likely, you'll end up having to specify the type when you bind (SQL_CHAR, for example) to affect its heuristics.

Please remember: post code and details so people can help.